# I get TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tkinter, floating-point

I would like to get the "Ok" print of a number (B = 2 + 2) if > to number that I insert in a textbox.

The first number is

```
A = 2 + 2

A = Entry (root, width = 4, highlightthickness = 0, bg = "# ffffc0")
A.place (x = 1, y = 1)

if B > A:
     print ("Ok")
```

I get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float'`

How can I solve?

Comment: Have you done print(type(number2))

Comment: @C.Pappy I want to print a message, I don't want to print number2

Comment: Add the statement print(type(number2)) before the comparison and let us know what you get

Comment: @C.Pappy I get the same error

Comment: Post the complete error message with full traceback.

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace you get as a result of the error?

Comment: `number2` is an `Entry` widget, so you cannot compare that with `number1` (which I guess is a `float` value)

Comment: @Selcuk In the traceback there is simply: if number1> number2: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'type'

Comment: @Kartikeya I know. I am looking for a solution for just that. Maybe an Entry conversion or something similar

Comment: The error you post in the comments is **not** the same as the one you post in the question.  How do you expect help when you don't give complete information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `Entry()` returns an object which is a text widget and is stored in `number2`. To get its contents, you need to call its `get()` method. The result will be of type `str`.

You will need to call `int(number2.get())` or `float(number2.get())` to get a variable whose type is compatible with that of the variable `number1` shown in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an `Entry` widget with a `float` variable.
[Refer to the documentation](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry), to know more.

So store the data (`textvariable`) of Entry widget in a `StringVar` variable  (For `double` values, you can use `DoubleVar` also in Tkinter), then while comparing typecast it to `float` or `int`, depending on what kind of number input is.

So, considering the number getting as input in the Entry box and the number1 are both **integer values** (can be large integers too, with **commas**.) I will store the numbers as **strings**. (If the values are decimals, use `float` instead of `int`.)

In order to **compare** the numbers stored in strings, I'll be creating a function `valueOf` to get the values of those strings as int with commas removed.

This snippet will give you an idea:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

number2 = StringVar() #take the input number2 as a string (so that commas are also included)
entry_1 = Entry(window,textvariable=number2) #assign number2 as textvariable of this Entry box.
entry_1.place(x = 1, y = 1)

def valueOf(s):
    if type(s) == str :
        s = s.replace(',', '')          #removes the commas from the number
        if s=="" :                      #in case nothing was given in Entry box, consider it as 0
            return 0
    return int(s)                       #return the integer form of that number
    
def Compare():
    #number1 = "2,552,555"              #make sure to take this number as a string if commas are there
    number1= 2+2                        #this is already in int form
    if valueOf(number1) > valueOf(number2.get()):
         print ("Ok")
    else:
         print("Input is Equal or Greater")

button1 = Button(window, text="Print", command=Compare)
button1.place(x = 45, y = 30)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have tried with both float and int. I am no longer receiving errors, but the text does not print. The numbers I would like to compare have commas, so should I use double? Should I use double instead of float or int? Should I also use DoubleVar instead of StringVar? Can you explain yourself better? Thank you

Comment: @Jas_99 could you please edit your question to show the exact code you have tried most recently, the value of the string in the text box (namely, the value in the variable `number2`) and the value of `number1`?